# Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \in C^1$ with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\not=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \in C^1$ with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\not=0$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}$ and $\psi: I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,\psi(x))=o$ for all $x \in I$, show that $\psi \in C^1$

ok this this is my idea:

Let $(x,y)\in  I$ then by hypothesis $f(x,y)=f(x,\psi(x))=0$ so $f(x,y)=0$. Since $f\in C^1$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\not=0$ then by 
Implicit function theorem  it follows that $\psi \in C^1$

Well, is this correct?

Comment: What is $I$? Domain of $\psi$?

Comment: It´s clear that $I \subset \mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: @jacques99 not when you write $\psi :I \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in I$, but apparently also $(x,y) \in I$. I understand what you mean, but you should be careful with notation,

Comment: @Dayton I was read Elon Lages Lima vol 2, you can read exercise 9.1 and Elon Lages write this that way.

Comment: Then it's bad notation. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo a typo, it is correct. You want to say: 'for all $x \in I$' instead of 'for all $(x,y) \in I$. Note that $I$ is an interval and thus does not contain elements of the form $(x,y)$.

When you see something that involves functions being defined by implicit relations, the implicit function theorem is your friend.